# JS audio jumping from a specifically set time back to 0 after it loads

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a function that loads an audio and sets the current time of the track based off of what the user was listening to the last time they had a page open. The track and progress into the audio is stored in localStorage. It works perfectly on localhost, but when I put it into a php server, the audio loads from the start.

Trying to find the source of the problem, I found out that it loads at the current time, then switches to 0 when it starts playing. Also, sometimes the audio file loads in twice, as shown in the network section of google developer tools (possibly because of native browser functionality and how video/audio files load). This is a major problem that is so frustrating because there is no signs of a problem whatsoever, except that it starts from 0 instead of the current time. I tried putting it in a oncanplaythough loop but that doesn't do any good either.

The code I currently have is (note that it is in a function and `time` and `src` are parameters):

```
//set the volume to 1
audio.volume = 1;
//set the current time to 0
audio.currentTime = 0;
if(muteSound === false) {
    //if the user didn't mute the sound, play it
    audio.play().catch(() => {});
}
//set the name of the music (for display)
let nameOfMusic = audioChoices.indexOf(src);
//if it exists, then set the name of the currently playing music
if(nameOfMusic !== -1) {
    localStorage.currentPlay = music[nameOfMusic];
}
//if the time (the code is in a function, time is the parameter. It gets set when the audio plays to the current time the user left off on) is not 0 (if the program didn't start a new soundtrack when the music ended), set the time to what it was previously.
if(time !== 0) {
    audio.currentTime = Number(localStorage.currentTime);
}
//set the currently playing source to the source of the audio
localStorage.setItem('currentPlaySrc', src);
//set the current time to 0 (the local storage value, not the actual value. This might be the problem here, as I have found that the music loads twice, meaning it will get set to 0 since the first time it loads it loads it to 0. However, I have removed this and it still doesn't work).
localStorage.setItem('currentTime', '0');
//set an interval that constantly sets the current playing variable in local storage to the current time of the audio and checks if the user muted the sound. It also checks if the audio ends and replays itself (the addMusic function is what this code is contained in)
let check = window.setInterval(() => {
    localStorage.currentTime = audio.currentTime;
    if(muteSound === false && soundMutedSession === true) {
        soundMutedSession = false;
        audio.play().catch(() => {});
    }
    if(audio.currentTime >= audio.duration) {
        clearInterval(check);
        localStorage.setItem('currentTime', '0');
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * audioChoices.length);
        addMusic(audioChoices[random], 0);
    }
    if(muteSound === true) {
        audio.pause();
        soundMutedSession = true;
    }
}, 1);
```

It's interesting that I didn't find any material on this. I don't think it has anything to do with typos or personal mistakes, but could it possibly have to do with how the browser renders and loads video/audio content?

Comment: I don't see `time` defined anywhere. Also, `audio.currentTime` is in seconds, so instead of `Number(...)` I would use `parseInt(...)`.

Comment: I explained that this is wrapped inside a function. `time` is a parameter. Thanks for the suggestion, but audio.currentTime is a  (stringified?) number, so `Number()` works.